# Crop Image To Center on Screen Resize with CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to take an image and center it on the screen. Lets say the image is the full width of your screen, say 1400px ---

When you resize the browser window, I'm trying to get the image to crop but stay centered as the browser window gets smaller.

Is this possible with css?

I tried a few things with overflow:hidden - no success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would take a look at background-size and then just center it vertically and horizontally.

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Thanks! Here is what I used: background: url('http://placehold.it/300x300') no-repeat 0 0;
 background-position:center;
        width:100%; 
        height:100%;