# CSS image crop and then resize

Tags: html, css

For my website I have an image that goes the full width of the page and dynamically resizes to suit the browser size. However rather than the image completely scaling, I would like the image to crop to a certain point and then resize. Like on the 'freelancer' website (if you make your browser smaller). I would like to achieve this, using CSS if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crop Image To Center on Screen Resize with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284159/crop-image-to-center-on-screen-resize-with-css)

Comment: Do you have any jsfiddle link for the problem ?

Comment: I can get the image to work so that it scales as the browser gets smaller, however I was wondering if there was simply a way to say that it can crop the image up to 1000px width and then rescale from there.

Comment: You can probably use a media query to change the css properties on the `<img>` to solve this but, as @Diptendu notes, please add a jsfiddle or code snippet to your question.

Comment: Please create mockup image(s) of the expected behavior.

Comment: How about `min-width: 1000px` -> for the page wrapper `<div>` or `<body>` tag? The background would scale with the wrapper. Once the wrapper hits the min-width it does not scale.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the cropping action you would like to implement. However, here is a basic solution using two wrappers:

2 wrappers are necessary because you can't make a div both 100% and min-width: 1000px. You can use css selectors to remove the tag soup. But this is the simplest solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/ty2kgm0u/2/

VYI - The jsfiddle is hard to test as you really need to test it out on a full html page.

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Background will show up here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
 width: 100%;
}
body .wrapper {
 min-width: 1000px;
 height: 80px;
 background: red; /* Use a background image to test it out fully */
}
```